# Symbian - Where I can find specification of the calendar file?

Tags: symbian

I want to write an application for syncing symbian calendar with my own software, where I can find specification for the file where Symbian writes all entries to the calendar ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the API to the Symbian calendar. Although there is a calendar database as an actual file, it is unlikely that you will be able to access this file directly.

You can find the documentation at [Using Calendar (CalInterimAPI)](http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/guide/Application-Engines-subsystem-guide/agnmodel/index.html). You can also look at [Calendar Interim API Example v1.1](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/18bc940d-2f0f-420d-b658-a50d2b860242/S60_Platform_Calendar_Interim_API_Example_v1_1_en.zip.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since interoperability is key here, why not use Symbian's support of the vCal standard?

See the documentation of the `CCalDataExchange` class in the developer library.

You might also want to check out the current work being done to support the newer CalDAV standard.

Shameless relevant plug: [Quick Recipes On Symbian OS](http://www.quickrecipesonsymbianos.com) contains a whole chapter about interfacing with the Symbian OS C++ Calendar API.